# WordPress: Filter custom post type conditionally

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am trying to make filters for a custom post type (bedrijf), where a visitor can make selections such as a category, an area and/or another criteria.

I do this by making a form with method=post and insert select options, where the values are in this case the category names and by approaching $_POST they can be inserted in a custom query.

Because not always a category is selected (or another criteria), I try to pass the tax-query variables in a single variable, so it can be left out the query when no category is selected.

So far I have the following part:

```
$taxquery = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !isset($_GET["orderby"])){
    if (!empty($_POST["category_bedrijven"])){
        $category = $_POST["category_bedrijven"];
        $taxquery = "'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'bedrijfs-category',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => '$category'
            )
        ),";
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'bedrijf',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        $taxquery
    );
}

$args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```

*(I know there is more needed, but for now, i focus on getting this working).*

The strange thing is: if I place the elements of the tax_query directly in `$args`, and pass the `$_POST["category_bedrijven"]` directly after the terms, the query works. If I put it together in a variable, it doesn't work.
I used `print_r` to print `$taxquery` and it returns the correct output. However, the query does not select the chosen category.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that was not smart. I should not have used the double quotes in storing the variable `$taxquery`, as it was saved as string.... Removing them made it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your variable inside of 'string' it will be used as a string with the value `$category`

But you want to use the value of the variable, so you don't need the string indicators:

`'terms'    => $category`